# Is there a simpler way to write this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is designed to make the sections display = none/block onclick, is there an easier way to write it so it is simpler and less lines of code.

I feel like I shouldn't need to rewrite it each time per every link and there should be a way to have 1 script that will work with the whole navbar.

HTML

```
  <header>
      <img onclick="video()" id="logo" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnrojsaks/image/upload/v1587122319/Icons/logo-no-text_yyug8o.svg" alt="Mac Logo" style="width: 10vw;" />
      <nav>
        <a onclick="contact()">Contact</a>
        <a onclick="work()">Work</a>
        <a onclick="blog()">Blog</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section id="main" style="display: block;">
        <h1>Mac Hooper</h1>
        <p><strong>Developer.</strong><br> Progressive, modern web development.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="contact" style="display: none;">
        <a href="mailto:macdevh@gmail.com">macdevh@gmail.com</a>
        <div id="social">
          <a href="https://instagram.com/machooper"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnrojsaks/image/upload/v1587129314/Icons/insta_maq9f2.svg" alt="Instagram Logo"></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/mac_hooper"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnrojsaks/image/upload/v1587129314/Icons/glab_jumort.svg" alt="Twitter Logo"></a>
          <a href="https://gitlab.com/macdevh"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnrojsaks/image/upload/v1587129314/Icons/twit_t57gos.svg" alt="Gitlab Logo"></a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="work" style="display: none;">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="https://lucycull.design" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><div class="card">
          <img id="work-img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnrojsaks/image/upload/v1587134668/Portfolio/lucy_ijnjoq.jpg" />
          <h2>Lucy Cull</p>
        </div></a>
      </div>
      </section>
      <section id="blog" style="display: none;">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="https://medium.com/@machooper_69036/make-vscode-yours-e362dab48ff6" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><div class="card">
            <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/600/0*ZdpEvxpU6_SFxDzT.gif" />
            <h2>Make VSCode Yours</p>
        </div></a>
        <a href="https://medium.com/@machooper_69036/my-setup-the-desk-5f4ed6824192" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><div class="card">
          <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*PFXyIbHjkQE-tGzlj6xMEA@2x.jpeg" />
          <h2>My Desk</p>
        </div></a>
        <a href="https://medium.com/@machooper_69036/my-current-tech-stack-10-04-2020-143feae97983" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a><div class="card">
          <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*qXN9PuwTmiHueFoeskJZnw.jpeg" />
          <h2>My Tech Stack</p>
        </a></div>
        <a href="https://medium.com/@machooper_69036/my-home-setup-the-computer-a6e67eb00e80" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a><div class="card">
          <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*PFXyIbHjkQE-tGzlj6xMEA@2x.jpeg" />
          <h2>My Computer</p>
        </div></a>
      </div>
      </section>
      <section id="video" style="display:none;">
        <video autoplay loop muted src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dnrojsaks/video/upload/v1587133353/Video/assets_img_header_bxtgiz.mp4"></video>
      </section>
    </main>
```

js

```
 <script>
    function video() {
      var main    = document.getElementById("main");
      var video   = document.getElementById("video");
      var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
      var work    = document.getElementById("work");
      var blog    = document.getElementById("blog");
      if (
        video.style.display   === "none") {
        main.style.display    = "none";
        video.style.display   = "block";
        contact.style.display = "none";
        work.style.display    = "none";
        blog.style.display    = "none";
      } else {
        video.style.display   = "none";
      }
    }
    function contact() {
      var main    = document.getElementById("main");
      var video   = document.getElementById("video");
      var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
      var work    = document.getElementById("work");
      var blog    = document.getElementById("blog");
      if (
        contact.style.display   === "none") {
        main.style.display    = "none";
        video.style.display   = "none";
        contact.style.display = "block";
        work.style.display    = "none";
        blog.style.display    = "none";
      } else {
        contact.style.display   = "none";
      }
    }
    function work() {
      var main    = document.getElementById("main");
      var video   = document.getElementById("video");
      var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
      var work    = document.getElementById("work");
      var blog    = document.getElementById("blog");
      if (
        work.style.display   === "none") {
        main.style.display    = "none";
        video.style.display   = "none";
        contact.style.display = "none";
        work.style.display    = "block";
        blog.style.display    = "none";
      } else {
        work.style.display   = "none";
      }
    }
    function blog() {
      var main    = document.getElementById("main");
      var video   = document.getElementById("video");
      var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
      var work    = document.getElementById("work");
      var blog    = document.getElementById("blog");
      if (
        blog.style.display   === "none") {
        main.style.display    = "none";
        video.style.display   = "none";
        contact.style.display = "none";
        work.style.display    = "none";
        blog.style.display    = "block";
      } else {
        blog.style.display   = "none";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a generic function that takes the section-name as parameter and then compute your style.display.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I would always make use of combining classes and Id. Yes I know maybe someone has a better approach but this for me always is easier.

NB: I just wrote this here I didn't test it if it has bugs comment I will check it but it should work 100%.

Your style

```
<style>
    .item
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style
```

Your HTML

```
<nav>
    <a class="link-item" id="contact">Contact</a>
    <a class="link-item" id="work">Work</a>
    <a class="link-item" id="blog">Blog</a>
</nav>

<span  class="contact item">Put your video here</span>
<span  class="work item">Your work content here</span>
<span  class="blog item">Your blog content here</span>
```

Jquery

```
$(function()
{
    $(".link-item").click(function(e)
    {
        var targetClassName = $(this).attr('id')  //get the id of the clicked item so that you can
                                                  //display it later
        $(".item").hide(function(e)  //hide all item
        {
            $("."+targetClassName).show()   //on callback display the item which was clicked using its classname
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I have done it with JQuery, you can convert this Jquery to Javascript. Your question was on Javascript so you might want JQuery or just do it with you Javascript but it should give you same results
I prefer JQuery(Javascript library) it's smaller and thus easily debugable. But if you want JS comment I can do it with Javascript